# file.delete() from android internal storage return false

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-file, internal-storage

I have a method to download a image from url and save it in a folder at Internal storage

```
 public void saveDynamicImage(String url,String fileName, String folderName) {

    InputStream iStream;

    BufferedInputStream buffInputStream;
    ByteArrayBuffer byteArray = null;

    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        iStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        buffInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(iStream, 8 * 1024);
        byteArray = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = buffInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            byteArray.append((byte) current);
        } 

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }

    File dynamicImageDir = context.getDir(AppConstants.DYNAMIC_IMAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File appNamefileDir = new File(dynamicImageDir, BaseActivity.appDataStore.getAppName());
    appNamefileDir.mkdirs();
    File controlNameDir = new File(appNamefileDir, folderName);
    controlNameDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(controlNameDir, fileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(byteArray.toByteArray());
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("DynamicImage saving over!..");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

i want to delete the whole directory at a point of time. My method to delete entire directory is

```
public void deleteDynamicImage() throws NullPointerException,FileNotFoundException {
    File rootDirectory = context.getDir(AppConstants.DYNAMIC_IMAGE, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    boolean status = rootDirectory.delete();
    Log.e("", "delete : "+status);

}
```

i am getting the status as 'false'. files are created and working fine. only problem in deletion. Is there any thing I am missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is your file a directory?

If it's, you need to delete file in this folder first
this code is work well

```
public void deleteDirectory(File file) {
    if( file.exists() ) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
            file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This method works for me. .. very good implementation.. Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the working method! Things like this bother me about Android development, there are so many quirks in the SDK where things should work but dont. You would think that if File object supports directories, then all methods should support both files & dirs - clear evidence of poor class design.

Comment: Works correctly but not is slow ? if you activate to 200 entries every time ?

Answer (score 6):

To delete Directory use this:

```
public void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
    DeleteRecursive(child);
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i am accepting the first received answer as the Accepted answer. thank you very much

Comment: No problem :)
which code you are using for ur implementation, just for curiosity :P

Comment: both code works well, but the code by 'henry4343' having a check for existence of file/directory. I have various sub folders and nested files. so i am using the answer from that user. Thank you..:)

Comment: Works fine, and seems that is fast

Answer (score 4):

**How to delete File in Android:**

```
public void deleteFile(String filePath){
    if(filePath.startsWith("content://")){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.delete(Uri.parse(filePath), null, null);
    }else {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            if (file.delete()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File deleted.");
            }else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete file!");
            }
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "File not exist!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Important Note:
if you get file path from Uri [**Don't use Uri.toString()**] as it will return file path in **file:///** format, in this case [**new File(filePath)**] will not work. So to get file path always use **Uri.getPath()**.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to delete a directory. `File.delete()` works on directory only if this is empty